# How to find 'alert-warning' in web page with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, alert

I have this HTML code:

```
<button ng-show="vm.loading_update" class="alert alert-warning">
  <strong>Upgrading firmware... Please Wait...</strong>
</button>
```

This alert message is open when a previous button was clicked (this is ok).
So, I have this small code but doesn't work, the alert message isn't found.

```
self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Upgrade"]')
self.elem.click()
time.sleep(1)

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                     "Upgrading firmware... Please Wait...")
alert_test = self.driver.switch_to.alert()
alert_test.accept()
```

I need to know if this message is displayed to continue the test...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because this is not a standard alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
try:

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".alert.alert-warning>strong")))

except:

    print("The alert is not displayed!")
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. And I will remove the "button" type, because doesn't make sense in this situation, because this alert message isn't a clickable item, is only information to user.